# How to pass data between any component using React context-API , without Provider being on top of hierarchy

Tags: reactjs, react-state, react-context

```
<Parent Component>       level-1
    <Child Component1>   level-2
        <Grand Child1.0> level-3
        <Grand Child1.1> level-3
    <Child Component2>   level-2
        <Grand Child2.0> level-3
        <Grand Child2.1> level-3
```

if we can't pass data without being on top of hierarchy(as per my understanding Provider has to be in top) any other solution (with context-api or without)

Answer (score 0):

Without a provider, you cannot pass data through all the way to all the components.[Check out this to learn more](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/usereducer-along-with-usecontext-react-hooks-b558be82dd4d)